# (Another) Alternative Proof to Baby Rudin 2.8

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Theorem: Every infinite subset of a countable subset A is countable.

(Note: below A is the subset of B)

I try to do the proofs on my own before reading Rudin's. Sometimes I fail heroically, sometimes comically. I can't see why I failed here, if I did.

Consider any $A\subset B$ where $B$ is countable. Assume for contradiction that $A$ is uncountable. Then, by definition, $\exists \alpha\in A : \nexists f(\alpha)\mapsto j\in J= \mathbb{Z}$. Because $B$ is countable, for $\forall\beta\in B, \exists j\in J$ and $\exists g:g(\beta)\mapsto j$ but this is a contradction because $\alpha\in A\subset B$.

edit: After a bunch of really unnecessary insults and vagueness, I see that the error is in my taking A from uncountable to there being no map onto Z. Thank you for everyone who (finally) helped me see that. It would have been very simple to point that out and explain it without all of the extracurriculars.

Also, I guess the re-tagging on this is OK, but it is literally in a book on analysis in a chapter called basic topology, so I'm not sure why my initial tags were wrong.

Comment: I'm aware of the source, but not its contents. Could you briefly mention what is established about cardinals in the book?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing in the proof. You need to show that if $B \subset A$ and $B$ is infinite then $B$ is countable. You can do so by constructing a bijection.

Comment: Also, since $A$ is countable, and $B \subset A$ you could simplify your life by taking $A= \mathbb{N}$ and $B \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I screwed up the terms, let me reformat.

Comment: Your definitions are badly garbled.

Comment: Can you explain which definition is garbled?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not even the hint at a proof. If $A$ is not countable, there does not exist a surjective function $B\to A$. Your $\exists a\in A:\not\exists f(\alpha)\mapsto j\in J=\mathbb{Z}$ means nothing at all.

Comment: Did I define such a function? I don't believe so. Sorry not sorry? I beleive it means that if A is uncountable then there is some element alpha in A such that there is no map between in and some set J equivalent to the set of integers, which is a definition given above in Rudin. But if it is countable then such a map exists.

Comment: Well, for example the definition of "$A$ is uncountable" does not read "$\exists \alpha\in A$...". Then when you say "$\not\exists f(\alpha)$" that's simply meaningless, since you haven't said anything about $f$.

Comment: Hmmm... my intent is that it read as follow: if A is uncountable then, by definition, there is some alpha in A such that there is no map f between alpha and some j in J for J equal to Z.

Comment: I understand that's your intent. That's simply not the definition of "A is uncountable"! It has a lot of words in common with the definition, but you've changed the order of the words. It's a _garbled_ version of the definition.

Comment: No matter what $A$ is and no matter what $\alpha\in A$ is, and no matter what $j\in \mathbb Z$ is, there _is_ a map $f:A\to\mathbb Z$ such that $f(\alpha)=j$. Obviously: define $f:A\to\mathbb Z$ by $f(x)=j$ for all $x$.

Comment: It might be quicker if you first stated your intent in English?

Comment: David, you *did* answer it here. That, I think is the problem. I think you could have said that at the beginning, but thank you for finally clarifying.

Comment: I retagged your question because the question is about countability of sets which is a concept of elementary set theory even though it shows up in other places. For example if you asked a question about why does $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$ that would be an algebra question even though the identity might be used in a real analysis book. I don't think your question is an analysis question because it doesn't involve analytical concepts such as continuity or limits. Similarly, I don't think it is a topology question because it doesn't use topological concepts such as open or closed sets.

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm: You are taking umbrage where there is none intended. Folks are trying to assist you here, it is unreasonable to expect that every single comment has to be exclusively focused on answering your question in the most expedient manner.

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm don't assume David was not doing his best to help you. It's just very difficult to find the right set of words that will be helpful. Learning is a complex process, and even if now it's clear to you what exactly helped you, it was probably not obvious at first that it would actually help.

Comment: If you want to see savage responses and unbridled rudeness you should try posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm I'm not sure which statement you're referring to when you say I could have said it at the beginning. My best guess is where I said "No matter what $A$ is...". That statement was actually irrelevant. You said the definition was [stuff]. In the statement I think you're referring to I explain why [stuff] is never true. That's irrelevant to the question of whether [stuff] is the definition of "A is uncountable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important when starting out to work with the definitions. The first definition we need is that $B$ is countable if (and only if) there exists a 1-1 correspondence (a.k.a. bijection)

$$ f : B \to J = \mathbf{N}. $$

Then if $A \subset B$ is an infinite subset (it should be $B \subset A$ if you're following Rudin's statement but I'll keep with what you're doing) we need to show that $A$ also satisfies the definition of "countable". By definition, this means that we need to show that *there exists a 1-1 correspondence*

$$ g : A \to J. $$

What you've done in your proof is show that "for all $\alpha \in A$, $f(\alpha) \in J$". Look carefully at what it means to be countable. Does this statement look similar to the definition of countable? Where's the 1-1 correspondence?

I assume you mean to take $f$ as your 1-1 correspondence. You're correct that it *is* true that if $f : B \to J$ is 1-1 and $A \subset B$ then $f : A \to J$ is 1-1 (show this).

However, pause for a second and think about this this: is $f : A \to J$ onto?

What you should realize is that the answer is: not unless $A = B$. For example, take $B = J$ and $f : B \to J$ to be the identity function: $f(n) = n$. Now consider the set $A = \{2,4,6,8,\dots\}$ of even numbers. The map $f : A \to J$ is not onto because there is nothing in $A$ that is mapped to $1$ (or $3$ or $5$ or ...). Rather, we need to construct a *new* function

$$ g : A \to J $$

such as $g(n) = n/2$. Then we have $g(2) = 1, g(4) = 2, g(6) = 3$, etc. This map $g$ is 1-1 and onto (show this).

I won't give you a proof of how to construct such a function $g$ in general (Rudin does that in his book). But I will give you the following picture. To say that a set $B$ is countable, means that we can number each element with the numbers $1,2,3,\dots$. So if $B$ is countable, we can write

$$ B = \{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}. $$

Now let's say that $A$ is the set

$$ A = \{x_2,x_4,x_6,x_8,x_{10}, x_{12},\dots\}. $$

We want to construct a new numbering $y_n$ such that

$$ A = \{y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6,\dots\}. $$

For instance, let $y_1 = x_2$ and $y_2 = x_4$ and $y_3 = x_6$. Then

$$ A = \{y_1,y_2,y_3,x_8,x_{10}, x_{12},\dots\}. $$

Do you see how we have sort of "pushed" the first three indices down: $2 \to 1, 4 \to 2, 6 \to 3$? This is the general procedure.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'm a bit confused because it was my intention to say by $\nexists f$ that there was no such $f$. In other words, there is no map in A because it is uncountable, but if A is a subset of B there is a contradiction.

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm You are confused. That makes no sense. For every $j \in J$ we can define a constant map $h(x) = j$ then clearly $h(\alpha) = j$. This has nothing to do with how big the set $A$ is. Even for the real numbers I can always find a function that maps any real number to any integer.

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm Btw, you never said $\not\exists f$. You said $\not\exists f(\alpha)$ - that's very different.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is countable then there is a bijection $i:A \to \mathbb{N}$, so 
we have $i(B) \subset i(A) = \mathbb{N}$, so to make things simpler
just take $A = \mathbb{N}$ to start with, and $B \subset \mathbb{N}$.

At this point you could note that since $B$ is infinite, there is a
map $j:\mathbb{N} \to B$ and invoke Schroeder Bernstein.

Comment: I understand the standard proof and many others given. My question is whether my particular proof is wrong and if so why.

Comment: Curious as to the downvote? Christmas spirit and all that happy stuff.

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote anything. But maybe someone objected to the "invoke S-B" in a context where we can't seem to state the definitions coherently?

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm Your proof is wrong. It makes no sense at all. You're not even stating definitions properly.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: :-). I am just being cantankerous as a consequence of seasonal viruses. I was going to write out the standard counting sort of proof but a muddled mind settled for a quick out.

Comment: Or maybe someone had issues with "Since $B$ is infinite there is a map $j:\mathbb N\to B$". There is a map from $\mathbb N$ to $B$ for any _nonempty_ set $B$...

Comment: I guess I should have written there is an injective map.

Comment: David: You have repeatedly said that and you are not adding anything to the discussion. If you would like to point out why, that would be great.

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm: The sentence started with 'Then, by definition' doesn't parse into a meaningful statement. That is why I suggested that you state your intent in English so we can assist with clarification. As is, the question is not clear.

Comment: The question was "what's wrong with my proof" regardless of what the content of the rest of the statement was. All you had to do was say what you needed to say in this comment and it would have been enough to help me go and rework it.

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm: I did make the suggestion in my last comment to the question?

Comment: @Jon-ErikStorm If I'd like to point out why? I've pointed out why the proof is wrong - you don't even have the defintiions straight! You say "since $A$ is uncountable, by definition..." and then what follows is simply not the definition.